# how to fix missing 1 required positional argument PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I tried to check the length of my training data to train the model but I got this error. I am implementing this in PyTorch. I have 3 main functions. dataset, extract beat and extract signal. can someone help to fix this issue, please?

> This is my dataset class

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, patient_ids,bih2aami=True):#This method runs once when we call this class, and we pass the data or its references here with the label data.
    self.patient_ids = patient_ids # list of patients ID
    self.directory="C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\list\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\\" # path
    self.nb_qrs = 99 #number of beats extracted for each patient, found that each recording had at least 99 normal beats 
    self.idx_tuples = flatten([[(patient_idx, rpeak_idx) for rpeak_idx in range(self.nb_qrs)] 
                               for patient_idx in range(len(patient_ids))])
    self.bih2aami=bih2aami
#if bih2aami==True:
 #   self.y = self.bih2aami(self.y)
def __len__(self):#returns the size of the data set.
    return len(self.idx_tuples) # length of the dataset 
def __getitem__(self, idx): # get one sample from the dataset 
    patient_idx, rpeak_idx = self.idx_tuples[idx] 
    patient_id = self.patient_ids[patient_idx] 
    file = self.directory + patient_id
    signal, normal_qrs_pos = get_signal(file)
    qrs_pos = normal_qrs_pos[rpeak_idx]
    beat, label = extract_beat(signal, qrs_pos)
    #sample = {'signal': torch.tensor(beat).float(),
     #         'label': torch.tensor(label).float()}
    print(patient_id, patient_idx, beat.shape,label.shape) # bug : what if label null ??
    X, y  = torch.tensor(beat).float(), torch.tensor(label).float()
    return X,y
```

> Get signal function

```
def get_signal(file):
record = wfdb.rdrecord(file, channels=[0]) 
df = pd.DataFrame(record.p_signal, columns=record.sig_name)
lead = df.columns[0] 
signal =  df[lead] #getting the 1D signal
annotation = wfdb.rdann(file, 'atr') #getting the annotation

relabeled_ann = bih2lamedo(annotation.symbol)
annotations = pd.DataFrame(relabeled_ann,annotation.sample)
normal_qrs_pos = list(annotations[annotations[0]=='N'].index) #normal beats
#normal_qrs_pos = list(annotations[annotations[0]!='O'].index) #beats
#normal_qrs_pos = list(annotations.index) #normal beats

return signal, normal_qrs_pos
```

> Get beat function

```
def extract_beat(signal, win_pos, qrs_positions, win_msec=40, fs=360, start_beat=36, end_beat=108):
"""
win_pos position at which you place the window of your beat
qrs_positions (list) the qrs indices from the annotations (read them from the atr file)-->obtained from annotation.sample
win_msec in milliseconds
"""
#extract signal 
signal = np.array(signal)
#print(signal.shape)
#beat_array = np.zeros(start_beat+end_beat)#number of channels
start = int(max(win_pos-start_beat,0))
stop=start+start_beat+end_beat 
#print(beat_array.shape,signal.shape)
beat =  signal[start:stop] 


#compute the nearest neighbor of win_pos among qrs_positions
tolerance = fs*win_msec//1000 #samples at a distance <tolrance are matched
nbr = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1).fit(qrs_positions)
distances, indices = nbr.kneighbors(np.array([[win_pos]]).reshape(-1,1))

#label
if distances[0][0] <= tolerance:
    label =  1
else: 
    label =  0 
print(distances[0],tolerance,label)
    
return beat, label
```

[image]

Comment: ```extract_beat``` expects ```3``` positional arguments.  You only have two in ```beat, label = extract_beat(signal, qrs_pos)```.  I'm guessing there should be a ```win_pos``` argument between ```signal``` and ```qrs_pos```.